# "Missing Join Predicate" with COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

I'm running into a situation where a query is running extremely long and the execution plan shows a MISSING JOIN PREDICATE right at the problem spot.

Here's the situation in example code (the real code is way too long to post):

Query:

```
Select a, b, c
from table1 t1
join view v1
on t1.id = v1.id
join table3 t3
on v1.value = t3.value
...more joining...
where [where conditions here]
```

View:

```
Select X, W, Coalesce(s1.value, s2.value, s3.value) as [value]
from table1 s1
left join table2 s2
on s1.id = s2.id
left join table3 s3
on s1.id = s3.id
```

So I have a query that uses a view which has a column that is created using COALESCE. This coalesce column is then used in the query to join to other tables, etc.

**NOTE: I have to use coalesce or something similar since I don't know which table (s1, s2 or s3) will be non-null and, therefore used for this column's value.**

The execution plan shows MISSING JOIN PREDICATE for the join using that coalesce view column. I'm assuming it shows this because the coalesce represents a non-deterministic value?

I've tried rewriting the query using a CTE or by adding the view code directly to the query itself...but so long as the coalesce statement is used for the join, I get the slow query times and MISSING JOIN PREDICATE.

The only way I've found around this is to use a temp table. I load the view results into a #Table and then join to the #Table in my query...when I do that it runs in 2-3 seconds and pulls back 73,000 records. If I use the first version of the query/view it runs 20+ min. and kills the tempdb.

I can use the temp table version but is there some more elegant way to deal with this situation...hopefully all within a single query?

Thanks,

George

Comment: Can you post the full query?  Having a half-written one is hard to debug.

Comment: Try simplifying the query to find the problem.  Then, if you can reproduce the problem using a shorter query, edit your question and include that one.

Comment: The syntax is correct, but the optimizer seems to have a problem with that join. It should do it similar to your workaround and materialize the result, but this seems to do a kind of CROSS JOIN. Are statistics up to date?

Comment: Use FULL OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN? (And all conditions moved from WHERE to corresponding ON.)

Comment: When you say you tried adding the view code directly to the query, did you try NOT joining on the coalesced value, but doing all the joins in the query, and only finally doing the coalesce in the outer select list?  IOW, outer join to Table3 three times, and coalesce all the columns you want to get from Table3.

Answer (score 0):

Doing joins on a view often performs poorly since the table doesn't really exist (its just a stored query that SQL runs when it needs it).  I would suggest using the select from the view in a sub query.  The optimizer should have an easier time working with that.

Select a, b, c
from table1 t1
join 
( Select X, W, Coalesce(s1.value, s2.value, s3.value) as [value]
from table1 s1
left join table2 s2
on s1.id = s2.id
left join table3 s3
on s1.id = s3.id ) as view1
on t1.id = v1.id
join table3 t3
on v1.value = t3.value
...more joining...
where [where conditions here]